# Matrix inverse algorithm that works for any unitary ring

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Is there any algorithm to

1. find out if a given square matrix has an inverse (which is both left and right inverse), and
2. compute the inverse, if there is one

for any unitary ring, without assuming that it is commutative and without assuming that it has the zero-product property?

Making a system of linear equations and solving it by substitution works correctly even for a non-commutative ring, but it can get stuck if there are some non-invertible non-zero elements. Finding the inverse by dividing the adjoint by the determinant works even for rings where not all elements have an inverse, because there are division-free algorithms for adjoint and determinant and we only have to perform one inverse operation in the very end of the computation, but it works only for commutative rings.

Comment: Multiply the adjugate of your matrix by the inverse of the determinant of your matrix. Of course, you'll have to compute the latter inverse for this purpose, but you cannot do any better (you cannot invert a matrix if you cannot invert a scalar).

Comment: See [Günter Rote, *Division-free algorithms for determinants and Pfaffians: algebraic and combinatorial approaches*](https://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/rote/Papers/abstract/Determinants+and+Pfaffians:+algebraic+and+combinatorial+approaches.html) for polynomial-time algorithms for computing determinants (and therefore adjugates as well).

Comment: Oh, I am seeing your ring may not be commutative. That makes it much more complicated.

Comment: I think I once learned that for non-commutative rings, the concept of a determinant isn't even (well)-defined. Might be wrong though...

Comment: Something interesting that I found out in the meantime. If a 2 times 2 matrix has at least one invertible element, then we can rearrange the rows and columns of the matrix, do an LDU decomposition, find an inverse if both elements of D are invertible and permute the result back. Triangular and diagonal matrices are very easy to invert in any ring. Unfortunately, the condition for the existence of an LDU decomposition for some permutation of the matrix is more complicated in the 3 times 3 case and I assume it only gets worse from then on.

Comment: Have you tried asking Christophe Reutenauer? This problem seems to be genuinely new, but Reutenauer is one of the people I suspect to have the best experience with things like it. (The Gelfand/Retakh/Reutenauer/Cohn school has studied the case of matrices over a division ring fairly comprehensively, though it is already fairly complicated.)

Comment: I don't think I'm going to bother anyone with a letter over this - I'm not a mathematician but a programming languages grad student and this question was just something I sidetracked into while implementing an algebra library for my language. I've taken a couple of undergraduate-level algebra courses and that's it. If the problem is as new and non-trivial as it seems from those comments, then the answer, even if there is one out there, might be beyond my comprehension. Thank you very much for the suggestion nonetheless :)

Comment: A cautionary example for the LDU approach: Let $R$ be the ring of $2 \times 2$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $A = \left[ \begin{smallmatrix} 1&1 \\ 1&1 \end{smallmatrix} \right]$, $A = \left[ \begin{smallmatrix} 1&1 \\ 2&2 \end{smallmatrix} \right]$, $C = \left[ \begin{smallmatrix} 1&2 \\ 1&2 \end{smallmatrix} \right]$, $D = \left[ \begin{smallmatrix} 1&2 \\ 2&4 \end{smallmatrix} \right]$. Then $\left[ \begin{smallmatrix} A&B \\ C&D \end{smallmatrix} \right]$ is invertible, although none of $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ are.

Comment: Over a local ring, you are in better shape: If a matrix over a local ring is invertible, then some entry must be a unit. For local rings, I think the LDU approach is $O(n^3)$, the same as computing inverses by row reduction.